# MYSQL How to make relation with no constrain

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, relation

Hello i am trying to figure it out this one.

I have 2 Tables

```
Sessions
id_session

Session_Requests
id_session
id_request
url
```

How can i make a relation between id_session that when i delete the session
the requests will still remain with that id_session

```
EX: 
Session id : 0923jguj45g8342

Request
id_session = 0923jguj45g8342
id_request = 1
url = https://example.com
```

When i delete the session with a relation i have a constraint that i cannot delete sessions anymore, or put null instead of session that is not good.

I want to have the relation so when i delete the Requests table will remain untouched.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Unless you have more columns you're not showing us in your "sessions" table, it seems a bit unnecessary. Specially since you have the session id in the other table as well.

Comment: I hate to disappoint but the whole reason for a relation *is* the constraint that says it must be there (or nullable). Using that model it forces you to say that all the references (id_session in table Session Requests) - they all point to an actual record (or none at all). Your own answer might be the be best.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245084/how-to-delete-a-row-only-in-parent-table-which-is-referenced-by-a-foregin-key-f and other similar questions. if you want to have FK relationship you have to cascade delete OR set null. Otherwise drop the foreign key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a row ONLY in parent table, which is referenced by a Foregin Key from the child table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245084/how-to-delete-a-row-only-in-parent-table-which-is-referenced-by-a-foregin-key-f)

Comment: I'd like to know - why the downvote?

Comment: yes, i dropped the foreign key so it has no constrains...

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible ?

Assuming that you have a foreign key on that column: no, this is not possible. You can't have a foreign key holding a value that does not exist in the parent table/column.

MySQL offers a kit of possible [referential actions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-key-referential-actions) that occur automatically when the reference row is deleted: `cascade` to drop the child record, `set null` to set the child key to `null`, or `restrict` to prevent the deletion. If one of those satisfies fits your use case, you can use it.

A possible alternative would be to create an additional column in the parent table that represents the status of the session, like `is_deleted` with a `boolean` datatype, and that you can set to some specific value (eg `1`) *instead of* deleting the record. This let you store the information without breaking the key.

Comment: But there is another option that you can put and that is "Do Nothing".

This option should work as intended. But is still telling me there is a constrain when i delete.

So yeah ... judging by the comments here it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your requirements, consider a "join table" (or "junction table", "reference table"). (aside:Does anyone use other terms for this relationship?)

Remove the "id_session" from the requests table and
include an additional table which should have two references - one points to the Sessions and the other points to the Session_Requests

```
T_Join_sessions_requests
  id_session  -- points to the session
  id_request  -- points to the request
```

whenever you insert a new request that is joined to a session you must insert the corresponding join entry.
whenever you remove a session you must also remove the join-table entries for that session, and leave the request table alone

When you first hear of this approach it is counterintuitive, but it's the best way to represent a many-to-many (and none-to-many?) relationships in a relational database. And you will find that actually makes coding to it much easier.